# Trying to run 2 dante servers on 1 vps

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

I purchased a vps for the purpose of using it as a socks5 proxy with dante, my vps has a second ip on the interface venet0:1, I'm wondering how I can use that ip as a proxy along with the ip on venet0:0.

This is my danted.conf file

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log
internal: venet0:0 port = 1080
external: 111.111.111.111 // actual ip is here
method: username none #rfc931
clientmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody
client pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    log: connect disconnect error
}
pass {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
    protocol: tcp udp
}
```